# Question about pullback and pushforward of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a projective morphism of schemes and $F$ a sheaf on $X$. There is a natural morphism
$$f^*f_*F\rightarrow F \ \ \ \ \ \ (*).$$
I have two questions about it.

(1) I heard that, if $Y=$Spec$k$ where $k$ is a field, then (*) is equivalent to

$$H^0(X,F)\otimes_k\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow F.$$

But I don't understand why in this case $f^*f_*F=H^0(X,F)\otimes_k\mathcal{O}_X$. I've tried calculate it by using the definition of $f^*$ and [Hartshorne, III, Proposition 8.5], then I got
$$f^*f_*F=f^{-1}H^0(X,F)\otimes_k\mathcal{O}_X.$$
But I don't know how to interpret $f^{-1}H^0(X,F)$.

(2) What if $Y=$Spec$A$ where $A$ is just a usual commutative ring? Does (*) implies
$$H^0(X,F)\otimes_A\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow F?$$
(By the same reason as above, I got
$$f^*f_*F=f^{-1}H^0(X,F)^\sim\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal{O}_X.$$
But then again I'm not sure where to go from here.)

Comment: We are treating $H^0(X,F)$ as a constant sheaf on $Y$. The definition of the inverse image sheaf is a bit complicated, but that complexity all collapses when you are working with a constant sheaf (or when $Y$ is a point), so $f^{-1} H^0(X,F)$ is just the $H^0$ now regarded as a constant sheaf on $X$, hence by the standard abuse of notation we can say that $f^{-1} H^0(X,F) = H^0(X,F)$ (perhaps that should be written in quotation marks; the point is ultimately that we have a free sheaf whose fibers are all canonically isomorphic to the space of global sections).

Comment: @TabesBridges OK, that makes sense to me when $Y$ is just a point. But what about when $Y$ is affine(e.g, question (2))? It seems that $H^0(X,F)^\sim$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y$ can't be regarded as a constant sheaf on $Y=$Spec$A$...（Perhaps I should ask first that if the first part of the question (2) is true )

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon X \to Y$ is any morphism of varieties, then there is a push-forward $f_*$ functor which takes sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules and produces a sheaf $f_*(F)$ of $\mathcal O_Y$ modules, and similarly a functor $f^*$ which "pulls-back" a sheaf $G$ of $O_Y$ modules to obtain a sheaf $f^*(G)$ of $\mathcal O_X$ modules.

**Pushing forward**:

The construction of $f_*$ is in some ways more straight-forward than $f^*$ for a couple of reasons: there is an obvious candidate for the space of sections of $f_*(F)$ over an open subset $U$ of $Y$, namely $F(f^{-1}(U))$, since the continuity of $f$ ensures that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. There is, however, a subtlety here, in that we have in fact defined a push-forward from presheaves on $X$ to presheaves on $Y$. However, it is straight-forward to check that $f_*$ restricts to give a functor from sheaves on $X$ to sheaves on $Y$. So far, everything we have done has only used the properties of $F$ as a sheaf, but it is also a (sheaf of) module(s) over $\mathcal O_X$, and we want $f_*(F)$ to be a sheaf of modules over $\mathcal O_Y$. What is needed to give $f_*(F)$ that structure, however, is given to us by the morphism $f$ however.

Because $f\colon X\to Y$ is an algebraic map, if $U$ is open in $Y$, then regular functions on $U$ yield regular functions on $f^{-1}(U)$ (simply by pre-composing them with $f$) and in fact this yields a map $\mathcal O_Y \to f_*(\mathcal O_X)$. Now $f_{\bullet}(F)$ possesses a $f_*(\mathcal O_X)$-module structure by the functoriality of $f_\bullet$, so that the functor $f_{\bullet}$ restricts from the category of all sheaves on $X$ to a functor from $\mathcal O_X$-modules to sheaves of $f_{\bullet}(\mathcal O_X)$-modules on $Y$. The algebro-geometric functor $f_*(F)$ is then the sheaf of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules obtained from $f_{\bullet}(F)$ by "restricting scalars" via the natural map $\mathcal O_Y \to f_{\bullet}(\mathcal O_X)$.

**Example**: I find it helpful to think through the special case where $X$ is affine and $f=a_X$ is the canonical map $a_X \colon X \to \text{Spec}(\mathsf k)$: if $F$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, $(a_X)_\bullet(F)$ is a module over $a_{\bullet}(\mathcal O_X) =H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)=:\mathsf k[X]$. The sheaf $(a_X)_*(F)$ is then a sheaf of $\mathsf k$-vector spaces on a point -- *i.e.* a $\mathsf k$-vector space, is obtained from $(a_X)_{\bullet}(F)$, using the inclusion of algebras $\mathsf k\hookrightarrow \mathsf k[X]$.  Thus the essential image of $\mathcal O_X$-mod under the global sections functor $H^0(X,-) = (a_X)_\bullet$ in $\mathcal O_{\text{Spec}(\mathsf k)}$-mod (which is better known as the category $\textbf{Vect}_{\mathsf k}$ of $\mathsf k$-vector spaces!) is the subcategory of $(a_Y)_{\bullet}(\mathcal O_Y) = \mathsf k[Y]$-modules.

**Pulling back**:

Now we need to understand pull-back: We first discuss the functor $f^{-1}$ which is the purely sheaf-theoretic pull-back operation, that is, it makes sense for any kind of sheaves (e.g. sheaves of sets) on topological spaces. Its definition isn't quite intuitive as that of $f_*$, but it is also quite natural. The difficulty is that, if $V$ is an open set in $X$, then the continuity of $f$ shows that the preimage $f^{-1}$ preserves open sets, but the image of an open set $f(V)$ need not be open, so we do not appear to have an obvious candidate for the sections of $f^{-1}(F)$ over $V$.

The solution is just to "approximate from above" as best as one can: that is, $f(V)\subseteq Y$ need not be open, but there is the non-empty collection $\mathcal C_V = \{U \subseteq Y: U \text{ open}, f(V)\subseteq U\}$ of open sets which contain it (non-empty because $Y\in \mathcal C_V$). The open sets are partially ordered by containment, and the restriction maps of a sheaf $G$ on $Y$ thus we define a presheaf on $X$ by setting
$$
f^{+}(G)(V) = \text{colim}_{\substack{U \in \mathcal C_V}} G(U)
$$
However, once again we have defined a functor on presheaves, but now, even if $G$ is a sheaf, $f^+(G)$ may only be a presheaf, and hence the functor $f^{-1}$ is defined to be the sheafification of $f^+(G)$.

However, as with $f_*$, we are not done because $f^{-1}(G)$ is not a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules. However, having considered the case of $f_*$, it should be clear how to obtain a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules: whereas for $f_*$ we obtained the $\mathcal O_Y$-module structure by "restriction of scalars" now we must extend them to form $f^*(G) = \mathcal O_X\otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal O_Y)}f^{-1}(F)$ where again, the functoriality of the sheaf-theoretic pull-back $f^{-1}$ gives $f^{-1}(G)$ the structure of a sheaf of $f^{-1}(\mathcal O_Y)$-modules.

**Example**: Let's see this in the case $a_X\colon X \to \text{Spec}(\mathsf k)$: if we start with a $\mathsf k$-vector space $V$, viewed as a sheaf on $\text{Spec}(\mathsf k)$, then $(a_X)^{-1}(V)$ is the constant sheaf $V_X$ on $Y$ with values in $V$ (note this gives an example where for general $X$ you have to sheafify the pre-sheaf pull-back), and
$$
(a_X)^*(V) = \mathcal O_X\otimes_{\mathsf k} V_X = \mathcal O_X\otimes_{\mathsf k[X]}(\mathsf k[X]\otimes_k V).
$$
where in the second equality we use the standard fact that $A\otimes_B B\otimes_B C = A\otimes_B C$. The reason for writing $(a_X)^*(M)$ in this arguably cumbersome way is that it show we may factor $(a_X)^*$ into a composition of the functor from $\mathsf k$-mod to $\mathsf k[X]$-mod given by the adjoint to the forgetful functor, $V \mapsto V\otimes_{\mathsf k[X]}\mathcal O_X$. Thus we obtain two adjoint pairs of functors
$$
((a_X)^{-1},(a_X)_{\bullet}) \text{   and   } (\mathsf k[X]\otimes_{\mathsf k}(-), \mathrm{Forget}^{\mathsf k[X]}_{\mathsf k}),
$$
where their composition is the standard adjoint pair in algebraic geometry, but it is also worth noticing that the pair $((a_X)^{-1},(a_X)_{\bullet})$ realises Serre's equivalence between the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$ and the category of (finitely presented) modules over $\mathsf k[X]$. That is, if $M$ is a $\mathsf k[X]$-module, the sheaf $M^{\sim}$ is precisely the pull-back $a_X^{-1}(M)$, and so
$$
H^0(X,F)^{\sim} = (a_X)^{-1}((a_X)_{\bullet}(F)) = \mathcal O_X \otimes_{\mathsf k[X]} H^0(X,F).
$$

**The case where the target $Y$ is affine**

Now suppose that $f\colon X\to Y$ where the target variety $Y$ is affine and that $F$ is quasi-coherent. Then $f_*(F)$ is quasi-coherent and by Serre's theorem, we have
$$
f_*(F) = H^0(f_*(F),Y)^{\sim}=\mathcal O_Y\otimes_{\mathsf k[Y]}H^0(Y,f_*(F)) = \mathcal O_Y\otimes H^0(X,F) = a_Y^{-1}(H^0(X,F)).
$$
where we used the fact that
$$
H^0(X,f_*(F)) = (a_Y)_*(f_*(F)) = (a_Y\circ f)_*(F) = (a_X)_*(F) = H^0(X,F).
$$

But now since $f^* = \mathcal O_X\otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal O_Y)} f^{-1}(-)$ we see that
$$
\begin{split}
f^*(f_*(F)) &=\mathcal O_X\otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal O_Y)}f^{-1}\circ(a_Y)^{-1}(H^0(X,F)) \\
&= \mathcal O_X\otimes (a_X)^{-1}(H^0(X,F)) \\
&= \mathcal O_X \otimes_{\mathsf k[X]}H^0(X,F) 
\end{split}
$$
where in the second equality we use the fact that the sheaf-theoretic pull-back functor satisfies $(f_1\circ f_2)^{-1} = f_1^{-1}\circ f_2^{-1}$.

Thus $f^*f_*(F)$ is the sheaf generated by the global sections of $F$, and the canonical map $f^*f_*(F)\to F$ is just the inclusion map of that subsheaf.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Still, I have some doubts about the second half of the answer(Starting with the word "Finally"): 1.Did you use "$\mathcal{O}_X$" to represent $F$ in the question? 2. What do you mean exactly by "everything can be recovered from the global sections algebra"? For (2), I know that $f_*F=H^0(X,F)^\sim$ is an globally generated $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. But how the global generation contribute to the question?

Comment: (Continue) 3. What is $H^0(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)_Y^\sim$ in the fourth line from the bottom of the answer? And why is the whole thing equalvalent to $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)_X^\sim$? 4. Just to clarify, from my understanding, the "$H^0(X,F)$" in the tensor product $H^0(X,F)\otimes_A\mathcal{O}_X$ stands for the global sections of $F$, not the sheaf $H^0(X,F)^\sim$, right?

Comment: I've rewritten my answer (more than I intended to to start with!) so that I hope I have now answered the questions in your comments above. The "everything can be recovered" comment was intended to mean Serre's theorem that quasicoherent sheaves have no higher cohomology on affine varieties so  $F= H^0(Y,F)^\sim$. I hope the clarification about $f_*$ and $f_{\bullet}$ clears up the confusion I caused writing $H^0(X,F)^{\sim}$. Let me know if there is anything that still looks questionable or confusing!

Answer (score 0):

a little extra remark adding to the other answers: If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbf{Spec}(k)$ is the map to a point, then $f_*\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{Spec}(k))=\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}\mathbf{Spec}(k))=\mathcal{F}(X)=H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$. This holds for any sheaf.
Note that for a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a projective variety $X$ this is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space (here you need your projectivity assumption). Then its pullback $f^*f_*H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$ is the sheaf on $X$ with stalk $\mathcal{F}_x=H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$ for every $x\in X$. It takes the same value every any point on $X$ and is in fact the trivial vector bundle of rank $dimH^0(X,\mathcal{F})$ after choosing a basis for $H^0(X,\mathcal{F})$. The map $f^*f_*H^0(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ is just the natural one: every global section gives a local section when restricting and this map you extend $\mathcal{O}_X$-linearily.
Note that this map is in fact surjective if $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by its global sections.